# Children's science fiction show with two robots on a planet of junk

Tags: tv, robots, story-identification

I've been trying to remember the name of a British children's science fiction show from (I think) the 80's.

The show revolved around two robots who lived on a planet made up of junk. I think the robots were also made up junk, one of the robots was bipedal (with wheels instead of legs) the other was I think dog shaped, and might have been made out of a scooter or a moped.

I think it was stop motion, like *Button Moon* or *The Clangers*, and I seem to remember the theme tune sounding like “Ashes to Ashes” by David Bowie.

Each episode revolved around them finding a piece of lost human technology and completely misinterpreting what it was.

To clarify:

There were only two robots in the show, as far as I can remember everything else on the planet had ceased to function.

I don't think it was a cartoon I think it was stop motion a bit like *Button Moon*.

The two characters were gender non specific though I think the implication was that the one that stood upright was male.

The one that stood upright pretended to be knowledgeable about everything the other one just went along with it.

There was an episode where they found a slot machine and they thought that it was a map of the stars with the lemons and oranges that came up representing different colored stars.

Comment: I wish, I've been Googling for it for two days.

Comment: I've been trying to find a show like this as well. All I can remember was a little robot trying to escape from being destroyed or captured. that then found 2 other robots that looked after it. And the parts that you listed.

Comment: The title made me think of the Junkion scenes from the original animated Transformers movie. Given the description though, that's obviously not it yet I still felt the need to comment.

Comment: You say original Transformers movie as if there has been a Transformers movie since then? I wish they would make a Transformers movie. Imagine what they could do with today's CG technology!

Comment: Well, unfortunately I had to add that 'lest someone think I was referring to the live-action nonsense.

Comment: I think you must be mistaken. There is no live action Transformers movie...

Comment: @OmarKooheji I have asked (and found the answer) the same exact question here: http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/31189/two-machines-isolated-on-a-planet-kids-show#31189

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A [similar question (now deleted)](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/31189/kids-show-about-two-robots-isolated-on-a-planet) came up over at Movies & TV and it's also what Omar is looking for, so I'll post the answer here as well.

[*CP & Qwikstitch*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0962827/combined) was a British kids show from 1985 about two robots from planet Junkus Minor, where all the broken machines from the galaxy ended up. They were made up of old machines; one was bipedal (and had irons for feet) and the other one was dog-like and moved around on a skateboard. The show was indeed stop motion, using *cutout animation*. There's an old clip available on [the RTÉ Archives website](http://www.rte.ie/archives/2014/1016/652830-robots-come-to-life/), and here's a picture from it:

[image: CP & Qwikstitch]

Comment: Oh my god thank you! My friends thought I was crazy talking about this show!

Answer (score 7):

## Runaway Robots! Romie-0 and Julie-8

> Romie-0 and Julie-8 is the third
>   animated television special made by
>   Nelvana Limited, inspired by William
>   Shakespeare's Romeo and Juliet. Set in
>   the future, the two romantic leads in
>   this version are androids who fall in
>   love despite a taboo against their
>   kind having such relationships.
>
> The special is also known as Runaway
>   Robots! Romie-0 and Julie-8.

[image: Image of characters]

Released: 1979
Filmed in: Canada

#### [IMBb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0079824/)

#### [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hx1jE0DVg2o)

#### [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romie-0_and_Julie-8)

Famous Quotes:

> If I didn't know better, I'd say you took a shine to that female junk pile.
>   -Mr. Thunderbottom
>
> What's the matter with you? You can't like that impertinent bucket of bolts!
>   -Ms. Passbinder
>
> You're just a robot. You can't have feelings!
>   -Ms. Passbinder
>
> If I can't have feelings, how come I'm feeling this way?
>   -Julie-8
>
> She's not just a junk pile. She's -- she's wonderful!
>   -Romie-O
>
> I'm glad you're here. I'm charging like crazy!
>   -Julie-8
>
> Our companies have hated each other for years. They'll never let us fuse.
>   -Romie-O
>
> Gizmo's the name, junk's the game.
>   -Gizmo

It was the first Google result for "[two robots who lived on a planet made up of junk"](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=two%20robots%20who%20lived%20on%20a%20planet%20made%20up%20of%20junk).

Comment: Not this. Sorry.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds vaguely like *[Little Robots](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_Robots)*.

> The show is centered on eleven Little Robots, each with his own distinct looks and personality. They were abandoned on a scrap heap in a junkyard until Tiny, the central figure of the story, fixed them. The robots set to build a world of their own, using junk to build their houses, gadgets, plants and flowers, and even their own sun and moon.
>
> The centre of their world is the Nut And Bolt Tree, a big, metallic structure that serves as a home to Tiny. Other important features of their world are the Day-Night lever, which causes the sky to rotate 180 degrees, switching from night to day; and the junkyard, that's constantly receiving junk from the surface through a chute.

Comment: That's not it. It's much older that little robots, and there were only only two robots.